# Google Translate API - PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-translate

I used google API to get address from given GPS coordinates. But this address language that I got, isn't suitable for me.

So I used also Google API for translation:

```
$from = 'en';
$to = 'tr';

echo "adress : " . "</br>".translate($from,$to,$address)."</br>";

function translate($from_lan, $to_lan, $text){

    $data = file_get_contents ( "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=" . urlencode($text) . "&langpair=" . $from_lan . "%7C" . $to_lan );

    $data = json_decode ( $data );
    if ( $data->responseStatus == 200 )
    {
         $data = $data->responseData->translatedText;
    }

    return $translated_text;
}
```

But this code doesn't work! The following error is occured :

**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\getAddress.php**

( $data = $data->responseData->translatedText; )

What shoud I do to solve this problem?

Comment: There is something wrong with the response json... `json_decode` is failing. dump `$data` and see what it looks like.

Comment: Didn't they turn off the free API some time ago?

Comment: @Pekka: [Apparently not](http://code.google.com/p/php-language-api/source/browse/trunk/google.translator.php)

Comment: @Truth but what about [this?](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html)

Comment: Try this http://rupeshpatel.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/usage-of-google-translator-api-for-free/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the API in question [is no longer publicly available](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html):

> Important: Google Translate API v2 is now available as a paid service only, and the number of requests your application can make per day is limited. As of December 1, 2011, Google Translate API v1 is no longer available; it was officially deprecated on May 26, 2011. These decisions were made due to the substantial economic burden caused by extensive abuse. For website translations, we encourage you to use the Google Website Translator gadget.

Comment: I truly wouldn't expect this from Google. They could just limit the requests.

Comment: True. They could have limit the requests.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to validate `$data` before using it as an object. `json_decode` doesn't *have* to give you an object.

- For debugging, examine the contents of `$data` (that is, just after you copy the translation response into it);
- For production, check the result of `json_decode` more thoroughly.

Comment: @iremce: I've said all I'm going to; examine the data you get from the server as your next debugging step. Also perhaps re-read the manual page for `json_decode`.